# Meaning of P0245 (16629) DTC on VW ALH TDI Engine

Tags: vw, diesel, turbocharger, tdi

I'm seeing a P0245/16629 – Solenoid Valve (A) for Boost Pressure Control (N75): Short to Ground – code on our 2002 ALH TDI. The solenoid valve controls the boost by moving the vacuum actuator that controls the turbo vanes. I think it does this by PWM (pulse width modulation) of the solenoid on the ground side. As I understand it, a (hard) short to ground would result in loss of control over the solenoid which should produce a full or even over boost condition.

What I'm actually seeing little or minimal boost. Vacuum is delivered to the actuator and I can see the actuator move. But boost pressure does not increase much (way less than the ECM is asking for) **and** the engine doesn't feel like it is getting any significant amount of boost (so while I haven't tested the MAP (manifold absolute pressure) sensor, I'm inclined to believe it.

So this leaves me wondering what the P0245/16629 code actually tells me. Does it indicate:

- That the ECM has measured the output pin for the solenoid and actually detected a short, or
- The ECM is unable to control the turbo output and infers a short as the likely cause.

Does anybody know? Both static tests on the solenoid wiring and its behavior strongly lead me to suspect that it is the later – I don't see a short to ground with a meter and the solenoid and actuator seem to be doing what the ECM is asking of them.

Comment: Nobody knows anybody who writes the firmware for engine controllers? :-(